# When was Cyberdyne Systems created in the original timeline and by whom?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

There is a cut scene from Terminator 1 (see video below at 3:31) indicating that Cyberdyne System existed prior to the first incident with the T-101.

The second film, however, indicates that Cyberdyne Systems investigated and exploited the technology they could salvage from the Terminator destroyed by Sarah Connor. Hence, I thought that Cyberdyne Systems was ***created*** to investigate remains of that first Terminator.

So, what exactly is their company history and how does the deleted scene (above) fit in?

Answer (score 8):

Cyberdyne Systems was, at least in the [novelization](http://www.shaunhutson.com/history.htm#terminator), the company whose building in which the showdown took place. At the time they seemed to be nobodies, just another Silicon Valley type firm. However, if they were also the firm which originally invents the technology, they'd also have the expertise to take the most advantage from reverse engineering future versions of that technology. They'd still do the same things, just earlier and faster.